# Does the group $G$ of $n$th roots of unity form a subring of $\Bbb C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it true that the group $G$ of $n$th roots of unity is a subring of $\Bbb C$?

My initial thought is that this is most definitely not true because the element $0$ is not an $n$th root of unity, and $0$ needs to be an element of the set in order for it to be a subring.

Sorry for the basic question. Thanks.

Comment: It is also not closed under addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that $0_{\Bbb C} \not\in G$ implies that $G$ is not a subring. Alternatively:

**Hint** What is $1 + 1$?